# Why am I getting System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, loops

I have read through similar problems to mine and haven't yet found a solution to point out my problem, or make it any easier for me to find.

I know that the error says that I am trying to reach something out of my loop can you point out where I am going wrong please and give any pointers what to change ect.

```
public int passSize;
public string availableChars = "AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIuJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz0123456789!£$%^&*()_-+=;:'@#~{[]}/?.>,<|¬`";

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = "";

    for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++)
    {
        if (passSize == 0)
            MessageBox.Show("You must select a password size", "Error");
        else if (passSize == i)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
            Random random = new Random();
            int r = random.Next(0, availableChars.Length - 1);
            sb[i] = availableChars[r];
            textBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried [stepping through your code, to determine the line the error occurs and identify what is out of range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more precise, this is where the problem occurs sb[i] = availableChars[r];

Comment: Read the documentation of `StringBuilder`. You should be using its [`Append`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yet24s7b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. `sb[i]` is incorrect - there is no element `i` existing yet.

Answer (score 0):

Basically your sb is only as 'big' as the text inside it, so when you try to set the ith character you get the issue, because the array isn't yet that big.

this is minimal code to reproduce your error

```
var sb = new StringBuilder("");
sb[6]='a'; //Will throw
```

NB there is a lot else wrong with your code,  but this is *why* you are getting the error you see.

Comment: Add in the quick fix (`Append()`), and I'll upvote you.